# context.drawImage function doesn't allow image persistence in fabric Js

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, fabricjs

I am using fabric Js on canvas where:
I am developing a product page for an e-commerce website where
I have drawn a background image and created a polygon on it and then inside of the polygon I have uploaded images, that works fine.

But now I have to make an image crop function inside the polygon for each image so that when I click on it I can crop it.

I have used canvas context.drawImage();. Function which works fine but when I click on the image or anywhere else on the canvas it disappears and I can't select it.
Can any one please help me with it ?

The code follows as

```
 var image = new Image();
 image.src = "uploads/cat.jpg";
image.onload = function(){
context.drawImage(image, 0, 19, 69, 97, 300, 100, 103, 145);
context.Image.selectable = true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I could be missing something here without seeing more context but I think if you used fabric.Image feature to draw your image instead of context.draw image it might work? Seems like there might be an issue happening with mixing fabric functions and regular canvas drawing.  [image.Fabric](http://fabricjs.com/fabric-intro-part-1/#images)

Sorry if I misunderstood! I'm a little fuzzy on the description of your image/shape stack order, screenshot might help if this answer doesn't apply.

Comment: actually the scenario is that i have a canvas and with fabric js i draw polygon in it, and inside the polygon i clip my images. now i want to crop that images so when i googled only i found the drawImage(); method for this work. i tried fabric.image method but  i cant crop my picture with it. it will add a new image object to my canvas.